# MongoError code: 40322, operationtime: 6978687905942208513

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I am facing operation time error when I tried to query the database. I am a newbie to the MongoDB.

Without using maxTimeMS in the following query, it is working for the first request but it's failing for other requests. (It is working only once)

Here is my query:

```
public async getItems(tenantDB: string) {
    let client: any;

    try {
        client = await mongoClient();

        const database = client.db("myDb");

        const collection = database.collection('InventoryItems');

        const query = [
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "InventorySubitems",
                    localField: "subItems",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "subItems"
                }
            }
        ]; 

        let items = await collection.aggregate(query).maxTimeMS(120000).toArray();

        if(!items.length) {
            await this.createDummyData(client, tenantDB);
            items = await collection.aggregate(query).maxTimeMS(120000).toArray();
        }

        this.logger.info('Successfully retrieved the items');

        return {
            code: StatusCodes.OK,
            data: items
        };
    }
    catch(err) {
        this.logger.info(err);

        throw ({ errMessage: 'Failed to retrieve the items' });
    }
    finally {
        if(!!client) // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
            await client.close();
    }
}


private async createDummyData(client: MongoClient, tenantDB: string) {
    try {

        const data = this.getDummyData();

        this.logger.info(`Adding ${data.length} records into InventoryItems`);

        for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            let curItem: any = data[i];

            const subItems: any[] = curItem.ApplicationFiles;
            delete curItem['ApplicationFiles'];
            
            const database = client.db(tenantDB);
            const subItemsCollection = database.collection('InventorySubitems');
            
            const subItemsResult: any = await subItemsCollection.insertMany(subItems);
            
            let subitemsIds: any[] = [];
            Object.keys(subItemsResult.insertedIds).map((key: any) => subitemsIds.push(subItemsResult.insertedIds[key]));

            curItem['ApplicationFiles'] = subitemsIds;
            
            const itemsCollection = database.collection('InventoryItems');
            const itemsResult = await itemsCollection.insertOne(curItem);
        }

        this.logger.info(`Successfully added the dummy data for the tenant: ${tenantDB}`);

    }
    catch(err) {
        this.logger.info(`Error while creating dummy data ${err}`);
    }
}
```

I have tried using different clients (Used new clients for each operation) for creating data and for retrieving the data. But facing the same issue.

For checking the database list I have used listdatabases operation but it didn't work, that's the reason I tried to fetch the items and if there are no items then it creates data.

Here is the error:

```
"operationTime\":\"6978687905942208513\",\"code\":40322,\"name\":\"MongoError\"
```

Where I am doing wrong..? Any assistance will be appreciated

Comment: Which part throws the error?

Comment: This part, let items = await collection.aggregate(query).maxTimeMS(120000).toArray();

Comment: I'm not finding '40322' as an error code for either MongoDB database or the node.js driver.  Do you have any more information about that error?